# Prove that a number consisting only of $7's$ is prime one time

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

$7$ is prime.

However, $77$ is not prime. $777$ is also not prime.

Prove that a number consisting only of $7's$ is only prime one time.

I think this amounts to proving that $7$ is always a factor of a number entirely consisting of $7's,$ for at least two $7's$ in said number.

Comment: yeah, they're easy to factor

Comment: feel free to answer

Comment: Easy to find one prime factor in any case.

Comment: I'm glad I asked this even though it seems obvious to everyone else

Comment: I am also glad you asked it

Comment: which numbers made up of all 1's are prime?

Comment: @JaneDoé Well, if such a number has $n$ $1$'s, where $n$ is a multiple of $3$, it's not prime for sure (since the sum of the digits would be a multiple of three). Not sure how precisely to handle the other cases but it's a start.

Comment: It can only be prime if the number of 1's is prime. even then it's not a gaurantee.

Comment: @JaneDoé You might find this OEIS sequence and Wikipedia article interesting -- https://oeis.org/A004023, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit

Comment: FYI, as described at [Primes without 7s](https://plus.maths.org/content/missing-7s), James Maynard has claimed to have proven there are an infinite # of primes that, expressed in base $10$, don't use the digit $7$ at all. In a certain way, this is basically the opposite of what you're asking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$7$ is obviously prime.

However, the successive numbers are obviously not. If the number is a repdigit of $n$ $7$'s, for $n\ge 2$, then the number factors into $7 \times r$, where $r$ is a repdigit of $n$ $1$'s.

For example:

- $77 = 7 \times 11$
- $777 = 7 \times 111$
- $7777 = 7 \times 1111$

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the number

$$\begin{align*}
\underbrace{7\cdot \cdots\cdot 7}_{\color{red}{n\text{ times}}}
&=7\cdot10^{n-1}+7\cdot10^{n-2}+\cdots+7\cdot10^{0}\\\\
&=7\cdot\left(10^{n-1}+\cdots+10^{0}\right)\\\\
&=7k
\end{align*}$$

for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 1):

Not only is a string of 7's not prime ( divisibly by 7). Even if it were, it would need a prime length. Because, if not, divide up the number into substrings of length a factor of its total length. This substring divides into each substring cut once, making it divide the whole number.